# Chart.js hidden graph until mouseHover after bower update

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bower, chart.js

I am using angular-chart.js and Chart.js to display some datas in my AngularJS application. I was using Chart.js (1.0.2) until now and everything was fine but I did update the Chart.js version (1.1.1) using bower. Now one of my graphs won't show when I refresh the page until a first mouseHover.

How can I address this issue?

```
<canvas id="line" class="chart chart-line" chart-data="data3" chart-labels="labels3" style=" width:500; height:300"></canvas>
```

And the JavaScript:

```
$scope.getServerDelay = function() {
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://****/delay?code=' + $scope.code
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {

        $scope.delayDatas = response.data[$scope.code][0];
        $scope.delayLabels = response.data[$scope.code][1];

        $scope.data3[0] = $scope.delayDatas.slice(0, 9).reverse();
        $scope.labels3 = response.data[$scope.code][1].slice(0, 9).reverse();            
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
            console.log('getServerDelay error :' + response);
});
```

Comment: Could you provide ur code snippet on how r u exactly using chart.js

Comment: The code is now in the first post :)